# AngularJS $http request takes far longer than hitting endpoint directly in browser

Tags: javascript, angularjs, wordpress, xmlhttprequest

I'm working on an AngularJS enhancement of a Wordpress website. I'm using the WP-API (v2) plugin to create custom endpoints and then consuming them on front end using Angular $http service.

Here's a code sample of the angular request:

```
function getData(slug) {
    return $http.get(endpoints.specialData.replace(':slug', slug)).then(function (response) {
        var data = response.data || {};
        return data;
    }, function (response) {
        return response;
    });
}
```

When I visit the page making this call I can see the time for this XHR (via Chrome dev tools) is about 4.5 seconds.

If I hit the same endpoint URL directly in the browser it returns the JSON result in 900ms. The endpoint URL is defined using a relative path (/path/relative/from/site/root) rather than the full http:// path, if that makes any difference.

Any ideas why it would take so much longer via Angular?

Comment: Could be browser cached version when you open directly. Make sure cache is disabled when comparing

Comment: Open your network tab and give us a break down of what part of the request is taking longer. My guess is this has nothing to do with angular or xhr, and instead is server/cache related.

Answer (score 0):

Debugging perf is quite particular, so all I can do is help you on your journey. You might want to take a look at troubleshooting the request using the Network tab in DevTools, and figure out what exactly is causing the slowdown. Read this article fully from Google: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/profile/evaluate-performance/timeline-tool

TL;DR If you see lot of green in your request, it's most likely a server issue, if it's blue, you're sending over too many bytes and need to optimize your JSON.

From there you can start narrowing it down.

Good luck!